# Best practice for sending query parameters in a GET request?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, http, backend

I am writing a backend for my application that will accept query parameters from the front end, and then query my DB based on these parameters. This sounds to me like it should be a GET request, but since I have a lot of params that I'm passing with some of them being optional I think it would be easiest to do a POST request and send the search params in a request body. I know I can convert my params to a query string and append it to my GET request, but there has to be a better way because I will be passing different data types and will end up having to parse the params on the backend anyways if I do it this way.

Answer (score 8):

This depends heavily on the context, but I would prefer using GET request in your scenario.

**What Request Method should I use**

According to the widely accepted convention, one uses:

- GET to read existing data
- POST to create something new

More details can be found here: https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

**How do I pass the parameters**

Regarding the way to pass parameters, it is a less obvious thing. Unless there's something sensitive in the request parameters, it is perfectly fine to send them as part of URL.

Parameters may be either part of path:

```
myapi/customers/123
```

or a query string:

```
myapi?customer=123
```

Both options are feasible, and I'd say a choice depends heavily on the application domain model. One popular rule of thumb is:

- use "parameters as a part of a path" for mandatory parameters
- use "parameters as a query string" for optional parameters.

Answer (score 4):

For simple frontend to backend communication you don't really need REST to start with as it targets cases where the server is accessed by a plethora of clients not under your control or a client has to access plenty of different servers and should work with all of them. REST should be aimed for if you see benefit in a server that can evolve freely in future without having to fear breaking clients as they will adept to changes quite easily. Such strong properties however come at its price in terms of development overhead and careful designing. Don't get me wrong, you can still aim for a REST architecture, but for such a simple application-2-backend scenario this sounds like an overkill.

In a REST architecture usually a server will tell clients how it wants to receive input data. Think of HTML forms where the `method` and `enctype` attributes specify which HTTP method to use and to which representation format the input to convert to. Which HTTP method to use depends on the use case actually. If a server constantly receives the same request for the same input parameters and calculating the result may be costly, then caching the response once and serving further requests from that cache might take away a lot of unnecessary computation overhead from the server. I.e. the BBC claims that [the cache is the single most important technology in keeping sites scalable and fast](https://www.creativebloq.com/features/how-the-bbc-builds-websites-that-scale). I once read that they cache most articles for only a minute but this is sufficient enough to spare them form retrieving the same content thousands and thousands of times again and again, freeing up the resources for other requests or tasks. It is no miracle that caching also belongs to [one of the few constraints](https://restfulapi.net/rest-architectural-constraints/) REST has.

HTTP by default will allow caches to store response representations for requested URIs (including any query, path or matrix parameters) if requested via safe operations, such as `HEAD` or `GET` requests. Any unsafe operation invoked, however, will lead to a [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) and therefore the removal of any stored representations for that target URI. Hence, any followup requests of that URI will reach the server in order to process a response for the requesting client.

Unfortunately caching isn't the only factor to consider when to decide between using `GET` or `POST` as also the current representation format the client currently processes has an influence on the decision. Think of a client processing the previous HTML response received from a server. The HTML response contains a form that teaches a client what fields the server expects as input as well as the choices a client can make for certain input parameters. HTML is a perfect example where the media-type restricts which HTTP methods are available (`GET` as default method and `POST` are supported) and which not (all of the other HTTP methods). Other representation formats might only support `POST` (i.e. while `application/soap+xml` would allow for either `GET` or `POST` (at least in SOAP 1.2), I have never seen `GET` requests in reality and so everything is exchanged with `POST`).

A further point that may prevent you from using `GET` requests is a de facto [limitation on the URI length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/1377895) most HTTP implementations have. If you exceed this limitations some HTTP frameworks might not be able to process the message exchanged. On looking at the Web, however, one might find a little workaround to such a limitation. In most Web shops the checkout area is usually split into different pages where each page consists of a form that collects some input like address information, bank or payment data and further input that as a whole act as kind of wizard to guide the user through the payment process. Such a wizard style could be implemented in this case as well. Parts of the request are sent via POST to a dedicated endpoint that takes care of collecting the data and on the final "page" of the wizard the server will ask for a final confirmation on the collected data and uses that resource as `GET` target. This way the response remains cacheable even though the input data exceeded the typical URL limitation imposed by some HTTP frameworks.

While the arguments listed by Always Learning aren't wrong, I wouldn't rely on those from a security standpoint. While it may filter out people with little knowledge, it won't hinder the ones for long with knowledge (and there are plenty out there) to modify the request before sending it to your server. So simply recommending using `PUT` as a way to making user edits harder feels odd to me.

So, in summary, I'd base the decision whether to use `POST` or `GET` for sending data to the server mainly on the factor whether the response should be cacheable, as it is often requested, or not. In cases where the URI might get so large that certain HTTP frameworks may fail processing the request you are basically forced to use `POST` anyway unless you can split the actual request into multiple tinier requests which act as wizard for the data collection until a final confirmation request triggers the actual final HTTP call.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using `POST` in the case where there are a lot of parameters/options. There are a few of reasons why I think it's better than `GET`:

- Your url will be cleaner looking
- You hide internal structure from the user (it's still visible if they use the Developer Tools of the browser though)
- People can't easily change the options to adjust your query. Having it in the url is simple to just modify and reload with other values. It's more work to do this as a `POST`.

However, if it's of any use that the URL you end up with can be bookmarked or shared, then you'd want all parameters encoded as part of the query, so using `GET` would be best in that case.

Another answer stated that `POST` should be used for creating something new, but I disagree. That might apply to `PUT`, but it's perfectly fine to use `POST` to allow more complex structures to be passed even when retrieving existing data.

For example, with `POST` you can send a JSON body object that has nested structure. This can be very handy and would be difficult to explode into a traditional `GET` query. You also have to worry about URL-encoding your data then decoding it when receiving it, which is a hassle.

Comment: While using post is a viable solution, mixing the verb when the request is technically a get operation (not creating or modifying state) is a questionable alternative.

Comment: I agree it’s not ideal but what do you feel is a better approach?